# How do I view the sync log for Firefox?

Tags: linux, firefox, browser, firefox-profile, firefox-sync

The page `about:sync-log` shows:

```
Index of file:///home/thufir/.mozilla/firefox/t0nel3vb.default/weave/logs/
```

How do I get more detail?  That directory is empty.  Can I receive these logs by e-mail perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I get more detail?  That directory is empty.

Normally the sync log only shows errors.

See below for instructions on enabling sync log on success.

> `about:sync-log` provides a list with log files and shows the location
>   where they are stored in the Firefox profile on the hard disc.
>
> **By default it shows only errors though**. Depending on how long you have worked without syncing it can take up to a couple of minutes to
>   be completed.
>
> Luckily you can configure Firefox that it writes log files on success
>   as well. Then all one has to do is hit reload on `about:sync-log` and
>   wait till the success log file appears or gets appended.
>
> There are a lot of setting that effect the sync process.  A lot of
>   timeouts and those kind of things,… I guess it's better not to tamper
>   with most of them. :-)
>
> **However, here's the trick that lets Firefox create/write log files on
>   sync success as well.**
>
> Type `about:config` and be super careful when changing anything.
>
> The parameter in question here is
>   `services.sync.log.appender.file.logOn`. Just type that into the
>   filter and two keys will be shown.
>
> ```
> services.sync.log.appender.file.logOnError default true
> services.sync.log.appender.file.logOnSuccess default false
> ```
>
> Change the latter one to `true` and keep an eye on the list shown when
>   typing `about:sync-log` in the location bar.
>
> Delete some of the files (in case this doesn't happen automatically —
>   I did not check) once you'll have got too many of those.

Source [How do I know that sync has completed successfully and that it is safe to close the browser?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/917119)